# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' - Getting this error and I have no idea why

Tags: python, string, types, operand

Currently creating a Cesears Cipher, in particular the decryption.

```
for char in decryptString:
    x = ord(char)
    x = x - decryptVal #this is my negative shift

    if x < 32:
        x = x + 32

    elif x > 126:
        x = x - 95


    result = result - chr(x)

print('')
print('Decrypted string: ')
print(result)
```

And I am constantly getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

instead of my decrypted message

No idea why, would appreciate some insight :)

Comment: what is `decryptVal `? Also you are subtracting a `chr` (string) from result, you can't subtract chars from anything

Comment: Does result need to be initialized first?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? `result = result - chr(x)`?

Comment: I don't know what `result` is, but `chr(x)` definitely is a `str` object. Not sure what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: What part of the error is unclear? Do you believe you should be able to subtract a string from a string, or do you believe you are subtracting a number from a number and thus think the interpreter is wrong?

Comment: He most likely meant to add chr(x) to the string, like `result = result + chr(x)`.

Comment: By process of elimination, it looks like the only line that could be generating that error is `result = result - chr(x)`.  Assuming this is true, you must be reaching that point without error, so you must have initialized `result` to some string value in code not shown.  Do you mean to be appending `chr(x)` to `result`?  That would seem to make more sense.

Comment: I was under the impression that I was subtracting my negative shift from my decryptString, which was converted into integers though ord(char) and then converting this back to a string, giving me the altered message.

Comment: That's what you are doing with all the modifications to `x`.  By the time you are working with `result`, you've already done all the calculation for the given character, so you just need to convert it back to a string and append it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't subtract a string off another string - which is what this error is telling you (you might have missed the '-' in 'unsupported operand type(s) for -' as it looks like a -:).

If I understand correctly what you're intending to do, you want to add the transformed character into the output string `result`. Strings support `+` for concatenation so do:

```
 result = result + chr(x)
```

You also need to initialise `result` before the loop, i.e.. `result = ''`